# Mocking an Aspect class invoked after an exception is thrown in Junit

Tags: spring, exception, junit, mockito, aspectj

I have an aspect class as below -

```
public class TestAspect {

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *(..)) ", throwing = "testException")
public void afterThrowAdvice(TestException testException) throws Exception {
}
}
```

Now anytime any class throws TestException, TestAspect's afterThrowAdvice method is getting called. From Unit tests as well without using any spring configuration xmls, running as a  plain junit test. How do I mock to not do anything when that method is called? I tried in my unit test the below but it won't work. Rightly so because the aspect is not autowired into the classes I am testing. Any suggestions? -

```
@Mock
private TestAspect testAspect

doNothing.when(testAspect).afterThrowAdvice(any(TestException.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is using `@Profile` option .

Following profile configuration will make sure the aspect bean is only available with the profile is not `test`

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Profile("!test")
public class TestAspect {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *(..)) ", throwing = "testException")
    public void afterThrowAdvice(TestException testException) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

and following Junit testcase runs the the tests with profile as `test` and no aspect bean is created here

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestExConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestService{

    @Autowired
    ServiceWithException service;

    @Test(expected = TestException.class)
    public void testExceptionMethod() throws TestException {
        service.testMethod();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps