# Disable certain aspects during ant tests

Tags: spring, junit, aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I've an aspect.

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    private MethodInterceptor myInterceptor;

    public MyAspect() {
      no-op
    }

    public void setInterceptorFactory(@NonNull final InterceptorFactory interceptorFactory) {
        //code
    }

    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(enableMetrics))
    public Object logAndProceed(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)  {
        return myInterceptor.invoke(new SimpleMethodInvocation(pjp));
    }
}
```

And I am using it like this

```
@EnableMetrics
public GetResponse getContract(args..) {
   //code
}
```

I am doing load time weaving of this aspect.

Now while running unit tests for `getContract` method, the aspect code also gets executed and it throws an NPE at return statement from `logAndProceed`.

All I want is  to disable aspect weaving for testing `getContract` method only.
Is there a good solution for it?

Alread seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433658/disabling-certain-aspects-during-unit-test-runs), it's not feasible to use if() pointcut right now.

Comment: You do not need an `if()` pointcut because that would be test-specific scode in your production code and also slowing down your aspects because the condition has to be evaluated during runtime for each and every matched joinpoint. You would only want to do that if necessary for your production aspect. Just configure your build tool not to put the load-time weaver on the JVM command line. I am a Maven person, so I cannot help you with Ant (I had no idea people actually still use it), but it should be straightforward in any build tool.

Comment: @de4shuch3da. I do not have expertise in LTW of aspect. I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60897010/4214241) something similar . Will using a profile help not to create an aspect bean for test ?